# Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals - AWS Cloudformation error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, amazon-kms

I have a CF template as shown below

```
 AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: gtm platform Lampda application deployment for ELasticCloud
Parameters:
  SystemUserAccount:
    Description: The syatem user account used to assume deployment role
    Type: String
    Default: usr-test1
  DeploymentRoleName:
    Description: The deployment role used to deploy cloudformation template
    Type: String
    Default: gtm-platform-deployment-role
  GTMPlatformLambdaRoleName:
    Description: The execution role for gtm platform
    Type: String
    Default: gtm-platform-lambda-role
  GTMPlatformKMSKeyAliasName:
    Description: The lambda function name for gtm platform
    Type: String
    Default: gtm-platform-kms-key
Resources:
  GTMPlatformLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    DependsOn:
      - GTMPlatformKMSKey
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref GTMPlatformLambdaRoleName
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2008-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: ''
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonVPCFullAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: GTMPlatformLambdaPolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action: cloudwatch:*
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:EnableKeyRotation
                  - kms:EnableKey
                  - kms:ImportKeyMaterial
                  - kms:Decrypt
                  - kms:UntagResource
                  - kms:UpdateKeyDescription
                  - kms:GetKeyPolicy
                  - kms:GenerateDataKeyWithoutPlaintext
                  - kms:CancelKeyDeletion
                  - kms:ListResourceTags
                  - kms:DeleteImportedKeyMaterial
                  - kms:DisableKey
                  - kms:DisableKeyRotation
                  - kms:ListGrants
                  - kms:UpdateAlias
                  - kms:GetParametersForImport
                  - kms:TagResource
                  - kms:Encrypt
                  - kms:GetKeyRotationStatus
                  - kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion
                  - kms:CreateAlias
                  - kms:DescribeKey
                  - kms:DeleteAlias
                Resource: !GetAtt GTMPlatformKMSKey.Arn
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:GenerateRandom
                  - kms:GenerateDataKey
                  - kms:ReEncryptTo
                  - kms:ReEncryptFrom
                Resource: "*"
  GTMPlatformKMSKey:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Description: Key used to encrypt decrypt EBS volumes at rest
      Enabled: true
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: Enable permissions for admin
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: !Join
                - ''
                - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
                  - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                  - ':root'
            Action:
              - 'kms:*'
            Resource: '*'
          - Sid: Allow access for Key Administrators
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/${gtmDeploymentRoleName}'
                  - accountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                    gtmDeploymentRoleName: !Ref 'DeploymentRoleName'
            Action:
              - kms:Create*
              - kms:Describe*
              - kms:Enable*
              - kms:List*
              - kms:Put*
              - kms:Update*
              - kms:Revoke*
              - kms:Disable*
              - kms:Get*
              - kms:Delete*
              - kms:TagResource
              - kms:UntagResource
            Resource: "*"
          - Sid: Allow use of the key
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/${gtmPlatformLambdaRoleName}'
                  - accountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                    gtmPlatformLambdaRoleName: !Ref 'GTMPlatformLambdaRoleName'
            Action:
              - kms:Encrypt
              - kms:Decrypt
              - kms:ReEncrypt*
              - kms:GenerateDataKey*
              - kms:DescribeKey
            Resource: "*"
          - Sid: Allow attachment of persistent resources
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/${gtmPlatformLambdaRoleName}'
                  - accountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                    gtmPlatformLambdaRoleName: !Ref 'GTMPlatformLambdaRoleName'
            Action:
              - kms:CreateGrant
              - kms:ListGrants
              - kms:RevokeGrant
            Resource: "*"
            Condition:
              Bool:
                kms:GrantIsForAWSResource: 'true'
  GTMPlatformKMSKeyAlias:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Alias
    DependsOn:
      - GTMPlatformKMSKey
    Properties:
      AliasName: !Join ['/', ['alias', !Ref GTMPlatformKMSKeyAliasName]]
      TargetKeyId: !GetAtt GTMPlatformKMSKey.Arn
```

I am getting an error when the resource `GTMPlatformKMSKey` is getting created. It fails with `CREATE_FAILED` and error message

```
Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException; Request ID: 5673456f-b458-45c6-854b-9ed63c737772)
```

If I remove the Sid `Allow use of the key` and `Allow attachment of persistent resources` from  `GTMPlatformKMSKey` the template runs fine. Not sure what I am missing here. Any help is much appreciated

P.S. - Resources `SystemUserAccount` and `DeploymentRoleName` already exists in the environment

Edit - As per the suggestion reduced the template to just include the failing resource

Comment: can the sid contain spaces. give SID a value without spaces

Comment: Can you please reduce the template down to the most relevant parts? (That is, remove the portions that do not impact your particular problem.) That way, we can attempt to diagnose or reproduce. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have reduced the template can you take a look now

Comment: Which particular policy is generating the error?

Comment: Why are you using the `!Sub` with a map/array? Pass it like a `String` e.g: ` !Sub 'arn:aws:ec2:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:vpc/${vpc}'  ` . The error is in the way how you are trying to construct the principal like here:  ``` Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Sub
                  - 'arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/${gtmDeploymentRoleName}'
                  - accountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
                    gtmDeploymentRoleName: !Ref 'DeploymentRoleName' ```

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The `Sid: Allow use of the key` is the one failing. I am trying to create the key and attach to the role in the same template. Is that an issue?

Comment: I agree with @OK999. Try simply using `!Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/${GTMPlatformLambdaRoleName}'`

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was trying to deploy a `CdkPipeline` stack that had stages with multiple accounts. I needed to run `cdk bootstrap ${account}/${region}` on each account and region where my stack was deployed.

```
cdk bootstrap 123456789012/us-west-2
cdk bootstrap 123456789012/us-east-1
cdk bootstrap 987654321098/us-east-1
```

I also had to give the second account permission as [per this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436197/aws-cloudformation-role-is-not-authorized-to-perform-assumerole-on-role).

1. Go to the Role in IAM
2. Select the Trust Relationships tab ...
3. Then Edit Trust Relationship to include `codepipeline`
4. Also add the arn of the other account's root

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codepipeline.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::987654321098:root"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to confirm that all the principal arn that you are assigning the resources to are available in your AWS account or have been referenced properly or they have the correct spelling in the template. Atleast these are what I experienced.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I apparently haven't created the IAM role in the external account which is why KMS in my primary account was complaining that "Policy contains a statement with one or more invalid principals."

After having created the role in the external account, CloudFormation successfully update the stack with KMS.

Comment: I had similar experience except that I was testing with "dummy AWS accounts" and got this error. Updating to use accounts that existed fixed the deployment issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the trust relationship from the cli with a flag in cdk bootstrap call:

```
npx cdk bootstrap \
--profile PROFILE2 \
--trust ACCOUNT1 \
--cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess aws://ACCOUNT2/us-east-1
```

[Reference article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cdk-pipelines-continuous-delivery-for-aws-cdk-applications/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the KMS users mentioned in the cloud formation template. It can be one of the reasons.