# Getting Error InvalidInputException: CodeBuild is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/MYROLE when creating project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-codebuild, aws-sdk-js

I am getting this error when using AWS javascript SDK to create a project in codebuild

> Getting Error InvalidInputException: CodeBuild is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/MYROLE when creating project

The role I'm using has attached the following default AWS policies:

- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess
- AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess

and the following trust relationship configuration:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
]}
```

Am I missing something? Is is possible to create a codebuild project from JS SDK? Does someone can show me an example? I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/javascriptv3-codebuild-src-createProject.js.html) documentation and tried many things i found about policies, roles, etc but I've been stuck here for some days already.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your trust relationship configuration is correct. Mine is the same as yours, and it works for me.

I think the problem you are seeing maybe similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60217010/9785462.

You may want to try create the IAM role first, and then the CodeBuild.